# Parse jQuery variable to PHP form to PSP shopping card

Tags: php, jquery, forms, parsing

I have to parse this jQuery output `<span id="chargetotal" class="chargetotal">Amount</strong></span>` to a PSP shopping card page.

From [this page](http://www.abbeyglen.ie/abbeyglen-castle-hotel/giftvouchers-test.php) i try to parse the 'Total amount' (Quantity * Value), and the rest of the form variables to the PSP shopping card page (`https://test.ipg-online.com/connect/gateway/processing`).

On the voucher page i include `ipg-util.php` which look like this:

```
<?php
$dateTime = date("Y:m:d-H:i:s");
    function getDateTime() {
        global $dateTime;
        return $dateTime;
    }
    function createHash($chargetotal, $currency) {
        $storeId = "XXX storeId XXX";
        $sharedSecret = "XXX sharedSecret XXX";
        $stringToHash = $storeId . getDateTime() . $chargetotal .
        $currency . $sharedSecret;
        $ascii = bin2hex($stringToHash);
        return sha1($ascii);
    }
?>
```

In [this instruction](http://www.authipay.com/assets/Authipay-IntegrationGuide-Connect-2.0.pdf) i setup **3.3 PHP Example**

The form look like this:

```
        <form method="post" action="https://test.ipgonline.com/connect/gateway/processing">

            <input type="hidden" name="txntype" value="sale">
            <input type="hidden" name="timezone" value="GMT"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="txndatetime" value="<?php echo getDateTime() ?>"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="hash" value="<?php echo createHash( "13.00","978" ) ?>"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="storename" value="XXX My store id XXX"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="mode" value="fullpay"/>
            <input type="text" name="chargetotal" value="13.00"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="currency" value="978"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="responseSuccessURL" value="http://www.abbeyglen.ie/abbeyglen-castle-hotel/voucher-succes.html"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="responseFailURL" value="http://www.abbeyglen.ie/abbeyglen-castle-hotel/voucher-failure.html"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
```

My problem is that in the above form example they use a strict value of 13.00 for `<input type="text" name="chargetotal" value="13.00"/>` to create the *hash* 'form variable'.

But in my case `chargetotal` is the 'Total amount' of the jQuery function in this HTML `<span id="chargetotal" class="chargetotal">Amount</strong></span>` .

See below, the jQuery script to get the 'Total amount'.

```
                 <script type="text/javascript">
                        $(document).ready(function(){

                        update_amounts();
                        $('.qty').change(function() {
                            update_amounts();
                        });
                    });

                    function update_amounts()
                    {
                        var chargetotal = 0;
                        var sum = 0.0;
                        $(function () {
                            var qty = $(this).find('.qty').val();
                            var price = $(this).find('.price').val();
                            var chargetotal = (qty*price)
                            sum+=chargetotal;
                            $(this).find('.chargetotal').text(''+chargetotal);
                        });

                    }
                </script>
```

How do i translate the jQuery 'Total amount' to a `<input type="text" name="chargetotal">`?

Thanks!

Comment: What jQuery variable and where can't you parse?

Comment: Hi, i update my question. Now it makes more sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
<input type="hidden" name="chargetotal" id="chargetotal" value=""/>
```

to your form. 
Remove `id="chargetotal"` from

```
<span class="chargetotal" id="chargetotal"></span>
```

Add

```
$('#chargetotal').val(chargetotal);
```

after

```
$(this).find('.chargetotal').text(''+chargetotal);
```

Comment: I put the ajax call on [this page](http://www.abbeyglen.ie/abbeyglen-castle-hotel/giftvouchers-test.php) but i get an error in the script. I already adjust `success:funcion` = `success:function` but still get an error. I also adjust those input fields: `<input type="hidden" name="hash" id="hash" value="<?php echo createHash( "13.00","978" ) ?>"/>` and `<input type="hidden" name="currency" id="currency" value="978"/>`. What do i have to do exactly with createhash.php ? What do i have to put in? Thanks

Comment: Put your `createHash()` function into `createhash.php` and a line `echo createHash($_POST['chargetotal'],$_POST['currency']);`.

Comment: Missing `);` at the end of ajax stuff (after `}}}`). And the ajax call should not be ready function, you have to call it after `$('#chargetotal').val(chargetotal);`

Comment: You mean this `createHash()` function from `ipg-util.php` ?

Comment: i still get an error: `$.ajax({url:authipay/createhash.php, type:"POST", data:{chargetotal:$('#chargetotal').val(),currency:$('#currency').val()}, async:false, dataType:text, cache:false, success:funcion(data,textStatus){ if(textStatus=="success"){ $('#hash').val(data); }}});`

Comment: Yes that createHash function. Maybe if you tell what error you get. Btw you should fix the `url:` it looks bad.

Comment: And what do i have to do with  `<input type="hidden" name="hash" id="hash" value="<?php echo createHash( "13.00","978" ) ?>"/>` It still has the value: `value="<?php echo createHash( "13.00","978" ) ?>"`. Do i have to change this?

Comment: in the code we just mist something i think like a bracket or semicolon. What is wrong with the `url:` ? I have `createhash.php` inside the directory `/authipay/`. Let me know i will change it!

Comment: Its ok, ajax will update the input. Ajax is runing in client browser, where no directory `/authipay/` exists. You have to write full url.

Comment: Yes stg like this, but make sure it is there and accessible. Atm it gives an "HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error"

Comment: On [this page](http://www.abbeyglen.ie/abbeyglen-castle-hotel/giftvouchers-test.php) input field is conflicting: `<input type="hidden" name="hash" id="hash" value="<?php echo createHash( "13.00","978" ) ?>"/>`. What do i have to do with the 'hash' input field? Thanks

Comment: And for testing i command `<input type="hidden" name="hash" id="hash" value="<?php echo createHash( "13.00","978" ) ?>"/>` out. But now when i look at my page my jQuery function `function update_amounts()` does not work anymore?

Comment: Change `dataType:text,` to `dataType:"text",`.

Comment: If no `<input id="hash">` exists, ajax can't update it.

Comment: ok that worked! And what about the `<input type="hidden" name="hash" id="hash" value="<?php echo createHash( "13.00","978" ) ?>"/>` ? Thanks a lot

Comment: now i have `<input type="hidden" name="hash" id="hash"/>` without `value` but when i test [the form](http://www.abbeyglen.ie/abbeyglen-castle-hotel/giftvouchers-test.php) is still get an error?

Comment: Look at your console. Your createhash.php generates an "500 Internal Server Error" page. Maybe has a parse error?

Comment: To avoid cross domain warnings, change url in ajax to `url:"http://"+window.location.hostname+"/authipay/createhash.php",`

Comment: **Internal Server Error** `File ".../authipay/createhash.php" is writeable by group.` Revoke group write permission on createhash.php.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65142/discussion-on-answer-by-mivanisten-parse-jquery-variable-to-php-form-to-psp-shop).